# how to hide keyboard when i touch screen in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

i am creating `search bar` in `iOS` when i press search bar keyboard will be appeared but after the search complete i want keyboard will be disappeared on screen.
i am implement code but its not hide .

```
 //this methos show to create dynamic search bar
-(void)SearchBarCode                                   
{
       //[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
       self.disableViewOverlay = [[UIView   
       alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,44.0f,320.0f,416.0f)];
       self.disableViewOverlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
       self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;

       theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-61, 46, 378.0f, 50)];
      theSearchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
       UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 46, 310.0,
       44.0)];
       searchBarView.autoresizingMask = 0;
       theSearchBar.delegate =self;
       [searchBarView addSubview:theSearchBar];
       self.navigationItem.titleView=searchBarView;
       scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
       theSearchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
       theSearchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void) dismissKeyboard
 {
       // add self
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
      [self.theSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
 }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
       [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 }

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {
        [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
        [theSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
 }

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {
        theSearchBar.text = @"";
        [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
        [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
 }

- (void)searchTableList
 {
        NSString *searchString = theSearchBar.text;
        filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       for (SMSCategory *cat in Arrayobject)
        {
             NSString *tempStr = cat.Name;
             NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options: 
             (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, 
             [searchString length])];
             if (result == NSOrderedSame)
             {
                 [filteredContentList addObject:cat];
             }
         }
 }

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {
      NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
      [self searchTableList];
      [self DynamicButton:filteredContentList];
 }

 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar activate:(BOOL) active
 {
      self.theTableView.allowsSelection = !active;
      self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = !active;
      if (!active) 
         {
           [disableViewOverlay removeFromSuperview];
           [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
         }
        else
         {
            self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
            [self.view addSubview:self.disableViewOverlay];
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeIn" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0.6;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            // probably not needed if you have a details view since you
            // will go there on selection
            NSIndexPath *selected = [self.theTableView
                                 indexPathForSelectedRow];
           if (selected)
           {
               [self.theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected
                                             animated:NO];
           }
        }
         [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:active animated:YES];
 }
```

.h File code

```
@interface CategoryMainWindowViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *Arrayobject;
    UIView *disableViewOverlay;
    UISearchBar *theSearchBar;
    NSMutableArray *filteredContentList;
    BOOL isSearching;
}

@property(retain) UIView *disableViewOverlay;
@property(retain) NSMutableArray *Arrayobject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *theTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *theSearchBar;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar activate:(BOOL) active;
- (void)DynamicButton:(NSMutableArray*)objectName;
- (NSMutableArray*)GetData;

 @end
```

Comment: check your becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not work as "becomeFirstResponder" shows the keyboard instead of hiding it! The hide-command would be resignFirstResponder, like this:

```
- (void) dismissKeyboard
    {
        // add self
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

**Edit:**
If the only thing you want is to hide the keyboard when the user has searched, it would be easier to just implement the **UISearchBarDelegate**-method

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

and call [self dismissKeyboard] from there, like this:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {
      NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
      [self searchTableList];
      [self DynamicButton:filteredContentList];
      [self dismissKeyboard];
 }
```

Comment: problem is that when i run my apps keyboard already appeared . i want keyboard appeared when i click on search bar

Comment: I'd suggest you remove every becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder except for your dismissKeyboard-Method. Then replace your code with what i suggested in my answer and try again. And remove your gesture-recognizer.

Comment: but one problem is there  my title is not display i am set my title in mains stroyboard .what the problem

Comment: What title do you mean?

Comment: means windows title like SMS Collection and all

Comment: self.title = @"Insta SMS Collection";

Comment: but its not set in my screen

Comment: Try self.navigationItem.title = @""

Comment: self.navigationItem.title=@"Insta SMS Collection";
    self.navigationItem.titleView=searchBarView;  i try this but at time only one statement work how its possible both are in one line

Comment: You know what, open a new question. Its not good to discuss this in comments.

Comment: how i can search content without press any buttons  means i enter text its automatically search a content .....

Comment: Open a new question. Ill be glad to answer, but not here in the comments.

Comment: i open new question check

Answer (score 1):

add this method to your view

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touching on screen");
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: can i know the reason?

Comment: when i click on search bar keyboard will be appeared but after that i touch screen its not hide

Comment: where you are calling dismissKeyBoard method

Comment: Have you added any scrollview or other view inside your main view? If yes then this will not work

Answer (score 1):

After `searching` happens you should call your `dissmissKeyBoard` method.

```
- (void) dismissKeyboard
{
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
     [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```